# Is it possible to find which process is using OPENSSL in linux?

Tags: linux, security, gcc, debian, performance-testing

Suppose, one process is running and accessing OPENSSL shared library to perform some operation. Is there any way to find the **pid** of this process ?
Is there any way to find on **which core** this process is running ?

If possible, does it require any special privilege like sudo etc?

OS- Debian/Ubuntu

Comment: `lsof`. all files held open by processes will be listed, including which .so libs they're using, and the associated pids.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for quick response. lsof is giving the process name, and it's pid. How to find which processor core is this program running?

Comment: that info's probably buried in /proc somewhere for the pid, but given that a process can be bouncing around cores randomly, the info may not be particularly useful.

Comment: @MarcB it's true that the process may be bouncing from one processor to another. However, if I use "watch -n 1 " <some command to find processor core>; this will give some hints whether it is moving or not?

Comment: @bholanath: what about processes with multiple threads? You could have 100 threads of a single process on each core... (and why do you need that piece of information, really?)

Comment: @thkala I haven't consider the case when a process has multiple threads . I think, in that case this will be complicated to find which thread(s) is(are) actually using the shared library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want, something like this might do:

```
lsof | grep /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so | awk '{print $1, $2}' | sort -u
```

This essentially:

1. uses `lsof` to list all open files on the system
2. searches for the OpenSSL library path (which also catches versioned names like `libcrypto.so.1.0`)
3. selects the process name and PID
4. removes any duplicate entries

Note that this will also output processes using previous instances of the shared library file that were e.g. updated to a new version and then deleted. It also has the minor issue of outputting duplicates when a process has multiple threads with different names.

And yes, this may indeed require elevated privileges, depending on the permissions on your `/proc` directory.

If you really do need the processor core(s), you could try something like this (credit to [dkaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35613594/507519)):

```
lsof | grep /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so | awk '{print $2}' |
    xargs -r ps -L --no-headers -o pid,psr,comm -p | sort -u
```

Adding the `lwp` variable to the `ps` command would also show the thread IDs:

```
lsof | grep /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so | awk '{print $2}' |
    xargs -r ps -L --no-headers -o pid,lwp,psr,comm -p
```

PS: The *what-core-are-the-users-of-this-library-on* requirement still sounds a bit unusual. It might be more useful if you mentioned the problem that you are trying to solve in broader terms.

Comment: thank you for prompt reply. You have explained beautifully. This will give which are the processes are using particular shared library. Can you please add , how to find which processor core these processes are running (as mentioned by dkaz),so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: I have checked the above command is not needed any root permission. However, this takes sometime to find the processes who are using the shared library. This may be due to lsof is listing all open files on the system as you mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

thkala is almost right. The problem is that the answer is half, since it doesn't give the core.

I would run that:

```
$ lsof | grep /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so |awk '{print $2}' | xargs ps -o pid,psr,comm -p
```

Comment: thank you for prompt reply. It is giving that pid also.